# Migrate Routes from Rails to Ember with Existing Rails Application using "ember-rails"

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, ember.js

Using gem "ember-rails" for an existing rails app. I'm attempting to route one resource using Ember, and I've been told by a number of people that this code should work, but it's not.

I want to breakthrough the learning curve and make this work, but I need some help.

**Error**

```
Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/newslinks"
```

**Code**

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-fileupload/basic
//= require jquery-fileupload/vendor/tmpl
//= require chosen-jquery
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-notify
//= require jquery.limit-1.2.source
//= require bootstrap-switch
//= require handlebars
//= require ember
//= require ember-data
//= require_self
//= require app
```

**app.js**

```
    App = Ember.Application.create({
  LOG_TRANSITIONS: true,
  ready: function() {
    console.log('App ready');
  }
});

App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('newslinks', { path: '/' });
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect: function() {
    this.transitionTo('newslinks');
  }
});

App.NewslinksRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
  return App.Newslink.find();
  }
});

DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({
  namespace: 'api/v1'
});

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 13
});

App.Newslink = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

routes.rb

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :newslinks
  end
end
```

application.handlebars

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="description" content="Ember - Latest" />
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Ember Latest</title>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/handlebars-1.0.0.js"></script>
  <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/ember-latest.js"></script>
  <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/ember-data-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2>Here I am</h2>
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Conclusion**

Please let me know how you would recommend setting up just one route: /newslinks through Ember and getting it to render using an existing rails route.

**This is not about the data (just want to render the route using ember). Also, this code works in jsbin, so it's also not about getting Ember to work independently of rails**

Do I need to direct rails to render a Ember route in routes.rb? Or is Ember routing sitting on top of rails routing and cherry picking the routes it recognizes?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the ember data with rest adapter the configuration is the following:

Given this url `your-host/api/v1/newslinks` with the following json structure:

```
{
  newslinks: [
    {id: 1, name: 'foo'},
    {id: 2, name: 'bar' }
  ]
}
```

You just need to map the newslinks routing:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('newslinks', { path: '/' });
});
```

And map the namespace in `DS.RestAdapter`:

```
DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({
  namespace: 'api/v1'
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/GkQ5x/) is a live demo using rest adapter and mocking the response.

By default rails will serve the json without the root path of the json:

```
[
  {id: 1, name: 'foo'},
  {id: 2, name: 'bar' }
]
```

To get this work easily, in a rails controller just add the `:json` to your `render` method, followed by the data. So rails will use the active model serializers, and the root path will be present:

```
def index
  @users = User.all
  render json: @users
end
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hey Márcio, I followed your instructions, but did not work. I still get this error: `no route matches /newslinks` I am trying to get the route to work, prior to allowing the data to be dispayed, but I can't get the page to even show up.

Comment: Do you want to make a single page app? Give a look in that repo by example https://github.com/wulftone/rails-ember-example

Comment: I think this problem is because you are trying to access `localhost/newslinks` instead of `localhost/api/v1/newslinks`. Please. Try access that second.

Comment: That gives me a blank page, whereas if I tack on `.json` i get my data back from that url. I think both of these urls are being handled by the rails router, right? What I'm looking for is how to create a new route and template for '/newslink' or '/newslinks' using Ember. When I go there, I still get a routing error. I don't need to connect to the data yet, I just want the page to show up.

Comment: Ok, you have to use `#/newslink` because ember respond to hashchange,by default. Try access that url http://localhost:3000/#/newslink

Comment: Interestingly, that gives me the home page from the rails app. From the console, I get this: `DEBUG: ------------------------------- ember.js?body=1:364
DEBUG: Ember.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.6.1 ember.js?body=1:364
DEBUG: Handlebars.VERSION : 1.0.0 ember.js?body=1:364
DEBUG: jQuery.VERSION : 1.8.3 ember.js?body=1:364
DEBUG: ------------------------------- ember.js?body=1:364
Uncaught Error: Attempting to inject an unknown injection: `store:main` ember.js?body=1:8069
`

Comment: I think that you will have to share more code. Sorry, I don't know what is that problem.