# Rerouting from existing Rails app to Ember

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ember.js

**Intro**

This is my first attempt at Ember (existing rails app) and there are some great resources out there on the interWeb, but given that I have read them all and am still wanting more it would be great to check notes here.

I have a new model: Newslink
I have built an api for it: `api/v1/newslinks.json`
The api works: `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/newslinks.json`

**Data**

`{"newslinks":[{"id":1,"title":"A Sample Post","navlink":"This will be a simple post record."}]}`

**Code**

The issue is that Ember seems to be letting the route slip through its hands (something I did wrong in the code below, I'm sure):

**application.js**

```
 //= require jquery
 //= require jquery-ui
 //= require jquery_ujs
 //= require jquery-fileupload/basic
 //= require jquery-fileupload/vendor/tmpl
 //= require chosen-jquery
 //= require bootstrap
 //= require bootstrap-notify
 //= require jquery.limit-1.2.source
 //= require bootstrap-switch
 //= require handlebars
 //= require ember
 //= require ember-data
 //= require_self
 //= require app
```

**app.js**

```
    App = Ember.Application.create({
      LOG_TRANSITIONS: true,
      ready: function() {
        console.log('App ready');
      }
    });

    App.Router.map(function() {
        this.resource('newslinks', { path: '/' });
    });

    App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
      redirect: function() {
        this.transitionTo('newslinks');
      }
    });

    App.NewslinksRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
      model: function() {
      return App.Newslink.find();
      }
    });

    DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({
      namespace: 'api/v1'
    });

    App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
      revision: 13
    });

    App.Newslink = DS.Model.extend({
      name: DS.attr('string')
    });
```

**Application.handlebars**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="description" content="Ember - Latest" />
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>Ember Latest</title>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/handlebars-1.0.0.js"></script>
      <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/ember-latest.js"></script>
      <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/ember-data-latest.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <script type="text/x-handlebars">
        <h2>Here I am</h2>
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Routes.rb**

```
App::Application.routes.draw do

  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :newslinks
    end
  end
```

I'm not even trying to return the data yet. Just want to see the route connect, but I'm getting a routing error. How do I make sure Ember sees the url "/newslinks"?

Let me know if you have any suggestions. Thanks!

**Random Unrelated Observation**

Ember.js seems a lot like reading Borges' *Labyrinths*, a good thing, and I can tell it will get much better on subsequent readings until everything just makes perfect sense.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Migrate Routes from Rails to Ember with Existing Rails Application using "ember-rails"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18091588/migrate-routes-from-rails-to-ember-with-existing-rails-application-using-ember)

Answer (score 1):

I would use chrome see what URL Ember is requesting. It is likely requesting '/newslinks' which is incorrect based on what you indicated your url was '/newslinks.json'

In which case I would change the route from '/newslinks.json' to a more appropriate REST url format of '/newslinks'

Comment: Hey Andrew, having a hard time parsing your answer. Can you point to places in the code that I would need to change to accommodate your answer (Ember being opinionated). I'm happy to provide more information if that helps.

Comment: Let me clarify the question first. After reading again I realized I may have misinterpreted. Are you having trouble getting to the '/newslink' route in the browser? or is the data not coming back to Ember from the API?

Comment: Getting a routing error. Not worried about data until I see the template render (with Ember).

Comment: root/#/newslinks returns the root of the rails app, home page, which is bizarre.

Comment: I updated the question to reflect the suggestions you've made (changes I made to the code locally) and that reflects everything that's in /javascripts for Ember. /#/newslinks renders the root of the application (rails current home page) and /newslinks returns a routing error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35073/discussion-between-andrewk-and-brian-mcdonough)

Answer (score 1):

To make it work redirect from your `IndexRoute` (which is implicit and created automatically) to your `newslinks` route sonce you have in your router map `/` as a path for your `newslinks` resource.

For example add this to your app and it should work:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect: function() {
    this.transitionTo('newslinks');
  }
});
```

Working [Demo](http://jsbin.com/epodih/2/edit).

Hope it helps.

Comment: That demo works, for sure, but I am still not able to connect via /newslinks. Routing error. I added my routes.rb above to see if that helps.

Comment: hhm, as far I can see your routes.rb looks fine (although I must admit I'm not fluent in rails)

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly what I thought would be challenging because you have two routers. I know others have made it work though, so I'll keep looking into it and post here when I figure it out.